# access violation error in c# when calling dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, vb6, dllimport

In Vb6 code like this:

```
Public Declare Sub PLCReadWord Lib "COM3964R.dll" Alias "plc_fetchword" _
                    (com As Long, _
                      Db As Long, _
                      Dw As Long, _
                      data As Long, _
                      RisOper As Long)
```

At C# side converted like:

```
[DllImport("..\\..\\dll\\Com3964r.dll", EntryPoint = "plc_fetchword")]
    public static extern void PLCReadWord(
        int com,
        int Db,
        int Dw,
        int data,
        int RisOper);
```

Compiling with Visual Studio 2013 - Framework 3.5 - x86 mode. My System has 64 bit CPU and 64 bit Windows 10.

When running the program system give an error at below code. I think `myDummyData` and `myDummyError` (both type `Int32`) can't written:

```
    ClassPLC.PLCReadWord(Convert.ToInt32(txtCommPort.Text),
                            Convert.ToInt32(txtDbRead.Text),
                            Convert.ToInt32(txtDwRead.Text),
                            myDummyData, myDummyError);
```

Comment: what is the error you are receiving?
when you're running the program, are you sure the dll is located up 2 directories then in a dll directory, in respect to where your application is running?
Is there any reason you can't distribute Com3964r.dll with your application, then remove ..\\..\\dll\\ from the DllImport?

Comment: Error is "access violation error was unhandled" at PLCReadWord function calling. In directory path notation no problem. PLCOpenPort and PLC ClosePort are running without problem. These are only send values the dll no wait any returned value. But PLCReadWord can't be able write myDummyData and myDummyError.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VB6 defaults by passing parameters `ByRef`. That corresponds to `ref` in C#. Change all the parameters in the C# declaration of the imported function to `ref`.